# Invoking read only ALTs/LUTs from CPI

Tags: solana-program

Exceeding computational limitations (due to non ALT accounts invoking).

When creating a transaction mainly versioned one, we can have ALTs which is nothing but a way to use read only accounts

in CPI accounts take 32 bytes
we on runtime can make it 1 byte and load it from ALTs

We will not store the ALTs in program, but what happens is it expands in the transaction and we are able to use that account as 1 byte storage, 1 ALT can store 254 addresses that I have seen to it's handy to use them to reduce the transactions size.

Any recommendations /doc on how to Invoke ALTs from a CPI stand point, front end wise/script is ok. Mostly from a program communication stand point.

It allows us to expand the account usage within our computation.